# dig returns ip addresses in differing order?

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

Pretty basic question here - when I run the command dig mx1.hotmail.com +short
to get the ip addresses of one of hotmail's mail servers, they return the same list with a different order every time.  I was wondering why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [round-robin DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS).

It allows some load-balancing by distributing the load on different servers.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [round robin DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS).